# DateTime not working in ASP.NET c#

Tags: asp.net

I have been working on a website for several weeks now in Visual Web Developer 2010 and I had been using DateTime all of that time. Suddenly it didn't work yesterday, throwing an out of bounds exception. I have saved progressive versions of my work now up to v.45 and none of the earlier work runs either. The following codes are a summary of what I'm doing but even on their own these are not working:

```
DateTime yearToday = DateTime.Today;       
string dtStr = yearToday.ToString("d");
```

Throws exception:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Also:

```
Label.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", DateTime.Now.Hour, 
                                          DateTime.Now.Minute, 
                                          DateTime.Now.Second);
```

Doesn't throw an exception but doesn't display.

Can anyone explain this?

@fpsColton: PC clock is working fine.

@Joe Enos: I only have VWD2010 and SQL setup on one PC. I haven't changed anything.

@Michael Liu: Here's the stack trace;

```
[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.] 
System.String.get_Chars(Int32 index) +0
Ref.genRef() in f:\WORKSTATION_Main\WebProjects\site\2014-12-11_ASP\site_40\don\pDon.aspx.cs:80
don_pDon.sessionString(String inRef) in f:\WORKSTATION_Main\WebProjects\site\2014-12-11_ASP\site_40\don\pDon.aspx.cs:165
don_pDon.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\WORKSTATION_Main\WebProjects\site\2014-12-11_ASP\site_40\don\pDon.aspx.cs:57
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51 
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92 
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Version Information:
Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237
```

Comment: Is your system clock set correctly?

Comment: Have you changed your regional settings in Windows to something funky, or messed with any regional settings in the registry? If you take that code to a different machine I'm sure it will run fine.

Comment: This code works fine on my machine, so the problem is elsewhere on your system.

Comment: [This code works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q3wEc9)

Comment: Post the entire stack trace of the exception you're getting.

Comment: What does DateTime.Now.ToString(); give as a result

Comment: What is happening at `pDon.aspx.cs`, line 80?  That's the point at which your code starts calling .NET framework code, according to the stack trace.

Comment: From the stack trace it would appear that the error has nothing to do with DateTime. It looks like you're indexing into a string inside of `Ref.genRef` and your index is outside the length of the string. Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to figure out what is going on?

Comment: @CraigW: Debugging gives the same Error message: "Index was outside the bounds of the array." Here's the first part of the code causing the exception: DateTime yearToday = DateTime.Today;

            string dtT = yearToday.ToString("d");

            char y1 = dtT[6];
            char y2 = dtT[7];
            char y3 = dtT[8];
            char y4 = dtT[9];//this is causing the exception, but whatever I do, it's only solved by deleting the whole method.

Comment: I wonder if I should reinstall windows rather than changing my codes and methods.

Comment: I created a basic asp.net page/website and tried the codes above. They work fine. The local server may have just stopped putting up with any inconsistencies in my html in my other website after this time. At least it's not my PC.